# Adding multiple USB 2.0 controllers - what are the options?

Tags: usb, pci-express, usb-3, usb-2

I'm trying to connect multiple (10+) USB 2.0 cameras to a computer that has only 1 USB 2.0 controller and 1 USB 3.0 controller.

From what I've learned basically the only option to increase available USB 2.0 bandwidth is to get more USB 2.0 controllers (possibly with multiple channels) and connect them via other interfaces. My question is therefore: what are my options to do so?

I've found out that there exist PCIe cards that add USB 2.0 controllers but the only models that I've found have only a single controller with single channel, while even the PCIe x1 bandwidth should allow for much more. Are there cards that have multiple channels? Or maybe there are other options? M2? USB 3.0? Please help me out.

Comment: Do you need the actual bandwidth or just more connectors? If so you could use a USB Hub.

Comment: Yes, I need actual bandwidth in this application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need multiple controllers, what you need are multiple channels/buses. You can't use USB hub, because that is still a single channel, but you can add one of the specialized PCI express USB 3.0 cards. For example I am using this: [Unibrain card](https://www.unibrain.com/products/dual-bus-usb-3-0-pci-express-adapter/) but there are many others.

If you really require multiple controllers, get a card similar to this:

https://neousys-tech.com/en/product/application/machine-vision/pcie-usb380

Comment: Ok, I understood that one controller==one channel but you are right that multi-channel controllers are also an option. So to clarify the initial question: I need multiple channels, not necessarily controllers.

Comment: My questions provides you 2 links, one for single controller with multiple channels, the other for multiple controllers. So what is your question now? You can search for similar cards from different vendors to fit your price range

Comment: I knew about the PCIe route, didn't know about the existence of multiple-channel cards so thanks for this (I unfortunately can't upvote due to <15 rep). I'm still curious about non-PCIe options, if any exist.

Comment: Accept the answer, others may upvote. I will look at non pcie options later...